# Analytical solutions to $E[f(X_\tau) e^{-\alpha\tau}]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $X_t$ be a geometric Brownian motion: $$dX_t=\alpha X_tdt+sX_tdB_t,$$
where $\alpha,s>0$ are constants. Let $\tau=\inf_{u\geq t}\{X_u=K\}$ be the first time $X_t$ reaches the threshold $K$ (from above). It's well-known that
$$E_t[e^{-\alpha\tau}]=\left(\frac{X_t}{K}\right)^{-\frac{2\alpha}{s^2}}.$$

---

A simple proof is that $E_t[e^{-\alpha\tau}]$ needs to satisfy the Cauchy-Euler ODE
$$ \frac{1}{2}s^2x^2u_{xx}+\alpha xu_x -\alpha u=0$$
which implies $u(x)=ax^{1}+bx^{-\frac{2\alpha}{s^2}}$. From the boundary conditions $\lim_{x\to\infty}u(x)=0$ and $u(K)=1$, we find $a=0$ and $b=K^{\frac{2\alpha}{s^2}}$.

---

#### Question:

I'd like to see how far we can push the availability of analytical solutions.$^1$

- Can we calculate $E_t[X_\tau e^{-\alpha\tau}]$ analytically?
- For what other non-constant functions $f$ can $E_t[f(X_\tau) e^{-\alpha\tau}]$ be computed analytically?

*$^1$analytical solution = closed-form solution typically only including elementary functions. It may require special functions but otherwise should not contain remaining integrals, etc.*

Comment: Stupid comments.  (1) I do not know how you prove that pde ? Maybe you can write how it is derived for inspiration ? (2) I am confused. It looks that $X_{\tau}=K$ by definition. Than $X_{\tau}$ is not a r.v. anymore and goes out of the expectation.

Comment: (3) is it correct this interpretation of the first equation: $X_t>K$ fixes the initial value at t (so it is not a random variable), and the expectation value on the left is over $\tau$ (an not on $t$) ? Otherwise could you specify what is a r.v. and what is not in that equation ?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your comments. (1) Let $u=E[e^{-\alpha\tau}]$. The ODE comes from $E[du]=\alpha udt$ and applying Ito's Lemma to $du$. (2) I think you're right. It's just $E_t[f(X_\tau)e^{-\alpha\tau}]=f(K)E_t[e^{-\alpha\tau}]$. Isn't it? (3) I indeed consider the case $X_t>K$ (wlog). Because it's a conditional expectation, $X_t$ is known. The stopping time is a number greater or equal than $t$ and is the random variable.

Comment: For point 2 exactly. That is at least what I think from your definitions and the result would be than trivial... Regarding point 1 do you have a reference? I am missing a -1 sign and why you have dt instead of E[d\tau]. Further since u is a deterministic function of t (you take expectations over tau), why you write E[du] instead of simply du ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments [*big thanks to @Thomas*], the answer is trivial. The stopping time $\tau$ is defined such that $X_\tau=K$. Thus, $$E_t[f(X_\tau)e^{-\alpha\tau}]=f(K)E_t[e^{-\alpha\tau}].$$

Comment: You are welcome :)